# connect() fails in Socket Programming Using IPv4 Protocol

Tags: c, sockets, ipv4

I am writing a client program, But the problem I am facing is `connect()` fails means return a negative number. I am following a book trying to write a program based on socket programming.
When a run the program from Command line `./out 169.1.1.1 "Hello World!!" 7`. After some time it displays ***connect Failed***

***Client.c*** I mean main.c in my Program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include "Practical.h"
    int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
        if(argc < 3 || argc > 4) {          //Program will be Exit if Invalid no. of Arguments is Passed.
            DieWithUserMessage("Program Arguments: ","Provide <./out, IP Address , Message and Port: 7>");
        }
        char * userIPAddress = args[1]; // First argument IP provide by the user separated by the . of 4 digits
        char * userMessage = args[2];   // Second argument message that user want to send to the server.
        in_port_t port = (argc == 4) ? atoi(args[3]) : 7; //4th argument which is : port number is optional , but if provided should convert to number.
        int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if(sock < 0) {
            DieWithSystemMessage("Socket Failed:");
        }
        //Now setting up Server Address
        struct sockaddr_in servAddress;
        memset(&servAddress, 0, sizeof(servAddress));
        servAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        int retValue = inet_pton(AF_INET, userIPAddress, &servAddress.sin_addr.s_addr);
        if(retValue < 0) {
            DieWithSystemMessage("IPv4 Conversion Failed");
        }
        if(retValue == 0) {
            DieWithUserMessage("Invalid, Pattern", "<IP Address Patern is Wrong/Miss spelled>");
        }
        servAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
        if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddress, sizeof(servAddress)) < 0) {
            DieWithSystemMessage("Connect Failed");
        }
        size_t messagelength = strlen(userMessage);
        ssize_t numBytes = send(sock, userMessage, messagelength,0);
        if(numBytes < 0) {
            DieWithSystemMessage("Sending Failed");
        }
        if(numBytes < messagelength) {
            DieWithUserMessage("Sending Incomplete", "<Greater or Less number of bytes is send>");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

***DieWithMessage.c***

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void DieWithUserMessage(const char* mesg, const char* details) {
        fputs(mesg, stderr);
        fputs(details, stderr);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(0);
    }
    void DieWithSystemMessage(const char* mesge) {
        fputs(mesge, stderr);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(0);
    }
```

***Practical.h***

```
    void DieWithUserMessage(const char* mesg, const char* details);
    void DieWithSystemMessage(const char* mesge);
```

***Makefile***

```
    # _*_ Makefile _*_

    out: main.o DieWithMessage.o Practical.h
        gcc main.o DieWithMessage.o -o out
    main.o: main.c
        gcc main.c -c
    DieWithMessage.o: DieWithMessage.c
        gcc DieWithMessage.c -c
    clean:
        rm -f *.o out
```

***Problem is occurring Here***

```
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servAddress, sizeof(servAddress)) < 0) {
            DieWithSystemMessage("Connect Failed");
        }
```

***Yet It is Incomplete I am going to write code for the server but first to solve this problem***

***Output***
[Output after Executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VElHd.jpg)

Comment: When a system or library call fails, either call `perror` or print the result of `strerror(errno)` before calling any other system/library function.  That will tell you *why* it failed.

Comment: `inet_pton(AF_INET, userIPAddress, &servAddress.sin_addr.s_addr)` should be `inet_pton(AF_INET, userIPAddress, &servAddress.sin_addr)`, but that is not the cause of the failure. Use `errno` to find out *WHY* `connect()` (or any socket function) fails.  Look a `perror()` to print a user-readable text message from `errno`. I suspect the failure will be related to you trying to connect to port 7, which is a reserved port on 'Nix sytems. Is there an actual ECHO server running on port 7 at `169.1.1.1`? Probably not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau when I use `ping 169.1.1.1` in cmd its working, sending/receiving packets. but here it does not echo my message back to me.
And secondly, I haven't use `perror()` before so I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @dbush how can i use `strerror(errno)`?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman It returns a string, so print it with `printf` or `fprintf` using `%s`.

Comment: @MuhammadSalman When I port-scan `169.1.1.1`, it doesn't find any open ports, least of all port 7. So you can't `connect()` to it. `ping` is handled with ICMP not TCP. `ping` is not the same as the ECHO protocol, which is what commonly uses TCP port 7. You can `ping` a server and still not be able to `connect` to it

Comment: @dbush okay i am trying to implement this.Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadSalman `void DieWithSystemMessage(const char* mesge) { perror(mesge); exit(0); }` or `void DieWithSystemMessage(const char* mesge) { char *details = strerror(errno); fputs(mesge, stderr); fputs(": ", stderr); fputs(details, stderr); fputc('\n', stderr); exit(0); }` or `void DieWithSystemMessage(const char* mesge) { fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", mesge, strerror(errno)); exit(0); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau i get this error after using `perror()`
`Error is: : Resource temporarily unavailable`
what is it?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman `"Resource temporarily unavailable"` is the text message for `EAGAIN`, which for `connect()` means "*No more free local ports or insufficient entries in the routing cache.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau what should i do Now, I mean any alternatives? 
Also i used you code. The one with `fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", mesge, strerror(errno));`
This gives me some warning as i have already included `errno.h`, and shows `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` at the output

Comment: You are approaching setting up the connection with a very dated method, see: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) Using `getaddrinfo` to setup the connection is quite a bit easier than manually configuring the connection parameters.